# Vue 3 If onbeforeprint and onafterprint are set in onMounted, do I need to reset them in onBeforeUnmount (and how)?

Tags: vue-component, vuejs3, onbeforeprint

In a VUE 3 component, I have set onBeforePrint and onAfterPrint thusly:

```
onMounted(() => {
  window.onbeforeprint = () => {
    clearPlaceholders();
  };
  window.onafterprint = () => {
    setPlaceholders();
  };
});
```

Do I need to unset these when the page unmounts and, if I do, what are best practices to unset these?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Listeners added on external elements ***<sup>1</sup>*** (body, window, document, ancestors, etc...) in `onMounted` hook should be removed in the `onBeforeUnmount` hook ***<sup>2</sup>***.

```js
import { onMounted, onBeforeUnmount } from 'vue'
//...

  onMounted(() => {
    window.addEventListener('beforeprint', clearPlaceholders)
    window.addEventListener('afterprint', setPlaceholders)
  })

  onBeforeUnmount(() => {
    window.removeEventListener('beforeprint', clearPlaceholders)
    window.removeEventListener('afterprint', setPlaceholders)
  })

//...
```

**Important:** To remove a previously bound listener, *the same event name and handler* must be passed to [`removeEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener) as the ones passed to `addEventListener`.
In other words, separate arrow functions running the same handler are separate handlers, because:

```
const a = () => clearPlaceholders()
const b = () => clearPlaceholders()
console.log(a === b) // false

// So this wouldn't work:
target.addEventListener(eventName, a)
target.removeEventListener(eventName, b)  // ❌ fails

// the listener is removed by:
target.removeEventListener(eventName, a)  // ✅ succeeds
```

Read [matching event listeners for removal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener#matching_event_listeners_for_removal) for details.

---

***<sup>1</sup>*** - cleanup is not necessary on elements contained inside component's template as they are garbage collected when the DOM elements are removed.

***<sup>2</sup>*** - The listener cannot be removed in the `onUnmounted` hook if it (the listener) is defined inside the component because at the time the `onUnmounted` hook is fired component contents have been deleted (in fairness, `onAfterUnmounted` would have been more useful for understanding when this hook gets fired).

---

**Reduce boilerplate (optional)**

If you find yourself having to add/remove a lot of events on external targets, you could reduce the boilerplate by using a composable:

```js
import { useEventListener } from './useEventListener'

  //...
  useEventListener(window, 'beforeprint', clearPlaceholders)
  useEventListener(window, 'afterprint', setPlaceholders)
  useEventListener(window, 'scroll', onScrollHandler, { passive: true })
  useEventListener(document.body, 'click', onBodyClickHandler, {
    capture: true
  })
```

And the composable - *useEventListener.js* - would look like this:

```js
import { onMounted, onBeforeMount } from 'vue'

export const useEventListener = (target, ...args) => {
  onMounted(() => {
    target.addEventListener(...args)
  })
  onBeforeUnmount(() => {
    target.removeEventListener(...args)
  })
}
```

Note this composable could only be used in `setup()` (or `<script setup>`).